# I entirely screwed up my build path/project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

All of my "folders" were being showed as packages and so on one of my packages, I hit "use as source folder" which converted it into a folder but seems to have make all other folders fall inside that folder...Is there any way to revert this change? After that I hit exclude from build path and it did some other weird thing. I'm not experienced with eclipse and probably screwed everything up.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]
http://i.gyazo.com/4846d8c628e3e6a9973b557884c0a74f.png

Comment: So instead of `com.apcompsci.game.entity` it should instead be `com.apcompsci`, `com.game.entity`, .... ?

Comment: I don't even think that that com should be there. To put things into perspective, my Game class is in my level folder but it should be in my game folder.

Comment: Right click on src folder->Build Path->Remove from Build Path. Then again right click on src folder->Build Path->Use as source folder.

Comment: thanks will try when i get home

Answer (score 1):

Right click on **src folder->Build Path->Remove from Build Path**. Then again right click on **src folder->Build Path->Use as source folder**.

Comment: this caused me to get a ton of errors. Can I upload the file and have you take a look at it ? Please, I need help urgently!! I'd be so greatful :)

Comment: Here it is after moving some files around to make sence. http://www.filedropper.com/gamesomewhatfixed and here is the origional messed up project http://www.filedropper.com/save.